# "Пол", "полу" - со словами

Tags: орфография

Как правильно писать слова, начинающиеся на "пол-" и "полу-"?

Comment: См. также: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/42021/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81-%d0%9f%d0%9e%d0%9b-%d0%9f%d0%9e%d0%9b%d0%a3

Comment: См. также: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/432539/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%93%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Приставка "полу-" всегда пишется слитно. А вот с "пол-" возможны варианты.
- Если слово начинается на согласную, то "пол-" будет писаться слитно.
Примеры: *полчетвертого, полстакана*.
- Если слово начинается на гласную, то "пол-" пишется через дефис.
Примеры: *пол-апельсина, пол-окна*.
- Если слово начинается на Л, то "пол-" тоже пишется через дефис. 
Примеры: *пол-лба, пол-лимона*.

Исключение:  *поллитровка*.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Если между "пол-" и словом есть другое слово, то "пол" пишется раздельно.
  Примеры: *пол третьего урока, "пол круглого стола*.
- С именами собственными "пол-" всегда пишется через дефис.
  Примеры: *пол-Африки, пол-Москвы*.

Comment: Правильно: пол-литра, а не поллитра. Никакого исключения нет.

Comment: Отвечающий, наверное,  имел в виду поллитровку.

Comment: "Поллитра" в значении "бутылка водки" пишется слитно. Оно и склоняется соответственно. "Съел поллитру".

Comment: Не путать с палитрой.