# Правописание сложных слов, начинающихся с ПОЛ-, ПОЛУ-

Tags: орфография, сложные-слова

Не могу нигде найти, когда пишется через дефис, когда нет, например: пол арбуза, пол года и т.д.

Comment: @Днеровский, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: См. также: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/113/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8

Comment: См. также: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/432539/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%93%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0

Answer (score 3):

ПОЛ- пишется слитно, через дефис или раздельно в зависимости от того, какая буква следует дальше, а ПОЛУ- пишется слитно всегда. Полугодие, полупальто.

ПОЛ- пишется слитно, если далее следует согласная, кроме Л.
ПОЛЧЕТВЕРТИ

ПОЛ- пишется через дефис, если далее следует гласная, буква Л или прописная буква (большая). ПОЛ-УРОКА,ПОЛ-ЛЕКЦИИ, пол-Москвы.

Раздельно пишется, если внутри есть другое слово.

ПОЛ УЧЕБНОГО ГОДА, ПОЛ ЧАЙНОЙ ЛОЖКИ.

Answer (score 3):

В приведенных вами примерах требуется дефис. Правильно: пол-арбуза, но: полгода. Читайте нижеприведенное правило.

[Тире между членами предложения](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=105#pp105)
***Дефисное написание сочетаний с пол- определяется правилом***
Сочетания с пол- форм род. падежа существительных (а также порядковых числительных в функции существительных), если эти формы начинаются с согласной буквы, кроме л, напр.: ***полбутылки, полведра, полдома, полметра, полчаса; полвторого, полдесятого, полшестого*** и т. п.
*Сочетания с пол- форм род. падежа существительных* (а также порядковых числительных в функции существительных), если эти формы начинаются с гласной буквы или с согласной л, напр.: ***пол-оборота, пол-окна, пол-апельсина, пол-узла, пол-избы, пол-епархии, пол-ёлки, пол-экрана, пол-юрты, пол-яблока, пол-лимона, пол-листа, пол-одиннадцатого.***Но: пол-Москвы (имя собственное). Подробнее об этом см. ***Полный академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина***.

Comment: Ым... Может тогда "Пол-ный академический справочник"?

Comment: @AnT, что вы имеете в виду?