# Как пишется "полрукояти"? Слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно

“Полрукояти” пишется слитно или раздельно? Почему?

Comment: Также см: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/42021/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81-%d0%9f%d0%9e%d0%9b-%d0%9f%d0%9e%d0%9b%d0%a3

Comment: См. также: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/432539/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%93%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0