# "Пол Гродненского района"

Tags: орфография

В тесте сочетание "... пол Гродненского района..." считается правильным. Объясните — почему?

Answer (score 3):

ПАС под редакцией Лопатина:
[ПРАВИЛА СЛИТНОГО, ДЕФИСНОГО И РАЗДЕЛЬНОГО НАПИСАНИЯ](http://orthographia.ru/orf.php?paragraph=pp153.php)

§ 153. Недопустимо слитное или дефисное написание с приставкой или первой частью сложного слова, если вторая часть содержит пробел, т. е. представляет собой сочетание слов. В этих случаях **слитные или дефисные написания, рекомендуемые основными правилами, должны заменяться раздельными**.
Например, следует писать: лже доктор наук, псевдо произведение искусства, теле круглый стол, мини стиральная машина,  пол рабочего дня, пол столовой ложки, **пол Московской области.**